# Jquery UI dynamic created button not fired the event

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery

I had created two buttons using Jquery UI and attached the following events to it.

```
function testconfirm() {
   alert( "testconfirm");
} 

function testCancel() {
   alert( "testCancel");
}
```

Only for the first time the event is not fired. after that its works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/qNGEw/26/

Can anyone help me to identify what's wrong with the code posted in the following Fiddle?

Comment: why are you binding and unbinding click events and the reason it doesnt work on the first click is because you are unsetting and resetting the click event in the function `test` and not actually triggering them

Comment: @Pascalz, Is it working when you click on Yes Button for the first time?

Comment: @PatrickEvans, its because,otherwise im getting two alerts for the second click and three alerts for the 3rd click and so on.. so each time im removing the event and binding it again. I dont know whether this is the actual solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always triggers click event, but you are doing it probably not the way you intend it to be.
First you are binding the events to both the button as test function. So first click executed the test function as its handler where you again unbind and bind the actual handler which alerts the message. So eventually from your second click onwards it executed the handler which has the alert.

```
 function test() {
            //Binding during the first click
            $('#btnconfirm').unbind('click').on("click", testconfirm);
            $('#btnCancel').unbind('click').on("click", testCancel);
        }
        var buttonPane = $("#message1");
        $.each(dialog_buttons, function (index, props) {
            $(buttonPane).append('<span class="ui-button-text" id="btn' + props.id + '">' + props.text + '</span>');
              //Binding for the first time
            $('#btn' + props.id).button().unbind('click').on("click", test); 

        });
```

You can easily resolve this binding issue this way:

When you set up the props for dialog button, add a property for handler as well.

```
var AlertTest = {
    "message1": {
        "buttons": [{
            id: "confirm",
            text: "Yes",
            handler: testconfirm //add one more property for the handler
        }, {
            id: "Cancel",
            text: "No",
            handler: testCancel //add one more property for the handler
        }]

    }
}
```

and just bind the event when you create the buttons.

```
 $('#btn' + props.id).button().on("click", props.handler);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QUTqx/)**

Comment: ok..So how can I trigger the events from the first time itself? I need to call testconfirm for the button btnconfirm and testcancel for the button btncancel. i tried like this         $('#btn' + props.id).button().unbind('click').on("click", '#test'+props.id); but its not working.

Comment: @user833985 see my updated answer with fiddle. You dont have to compliate it much.